# Dispersion, refractive index against frequency graph

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction, dispersion

From Hecht optics page 74, the plot of $n$ , the refractive index, against $\omega$ , the angular frequency of the incoming wave is

[image]

And the relation between $n$ and $\omega$ is:

[image]

Where each $\omega_{0_{j}}$ are resonant frequencies and $\gamma_{j}$ are the corresponding damping parameters, $f_{j}$ are weighting factors such that $\sum_{j} f_{j} = 1$.

Now what I don't understand in the graph, is that at each $\omega = \omega_{0_{j}}$ , $n$ is equal to $1$, I can't see how that follows from the equation, I think in order for $n$ to equal $1$ at these resonant frequencies, the sum has to equal zero, but I don't see how.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about microscopic and macroscopic properties. The formula you show is usually written like (http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/jk1/lectures/node68.html) in which n=1 at resonance is obvious. The formula you have seems to come from some weird adaptation of Clausius-Mossotti (http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/jk1/lectures/node45.html) which is relating the microscopic polarizability to the macroscopic.

Comment: Still for that formula you provided in the link, how is n=1 at resonance obvious?

Comment: Consider Eq.785 in said link. (a) We neglect other resonances (assume the frequencies are spaced far apart). Thus we only have to consider 1 term in the sum. (b) At resonance the term is purely imaginary. Thus the real part is 1.